# SignalR connect never ends

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, signalr

When I am trying to use AspNetCore SignalR in my Windows Forms application, `hubconnecion.StartAsync` never ends, and never throws an error or excpetion.

No matter if Hub is running or not, it only reacts if ctor has incorrect URL. If you'll try to use `.Wait()` it won't make any effect, it will just freeze

Client part:

```
    HubConnection hub;
    hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:5032").Build();
    hub.StartAsync().Wait();
```

I tried'to make .netCore console app, and it's work great, don't know why I can't make it run on WindowsForm application? I thought AspNetCore SignalR uses.NetStandart that should allow me to use it.

P.s I know about another .netframework aspnet signalR but its old, and I have another more complicated issue with it.

Comment: Add a piece of code that you use. It's hard to tell what's going on with this description.